# Black screen and sound stops working but pc is still running

Tags: windows-10, audio, gpu, power, windows-installer

Suddenly at random times (whether I'm playing or doing something else) both screens go black and sound stops working. However PC is still running, but I can't do nothing, I even can't see my cursor. One thing I can do is to restart my PC and then it is all fine.

**What I've also encountered:** A few weeks ago, my computer shut down completely, and when I wanted to turn it on, it completely didn't see my drive on which the system is installed. However, after waiting about 15 minutes I tried to turn on my computer again, and then the disk was visible in BIOS and I could run it without any problems.

**My hardware:**

- Motherboard: MSI Z170A Gaming Pro
- Graphics Card: MSI R9 380 4G
- CPU: i5 6600K Skylake

**What I've tried:**

- Reinstalled GPU drivers
- Updated my Windows10
- Checked the temperatures on my GPU and CPU

**Update 09.05.21**
After many attempts, I did a fresh install of the system, installed all the drivers and only the necessary programs. The problem seemed to be with the system. However, today the black screen is back. I checked the debug leds on the motherboard and again in this case none of the LEDs were on, so I bet it's not a hardware issue (RAM, GPU, CPU).

**Oddly enough, I noticed**
As soon as the black screen appeared, the second monitor completely lost signal and the main monitor shows the black screen. The leds on the keyboard and other usb devices are on, so they have to be powered. The system must be turned off or somehow suspended, because when I click capslock f.e., the LED on the keyboard does not light up (I bet that the keyboard driver does not receive a signal from the system). Also when black screen occurs, fans on GPU are working. I don't know where the problem could lie. I think it is worth mentioning that my setup contains two monitors each connected to DVI.

**Update 10.05.21**
Interval between black screens has changed from 3 days to 2 hours.

Comment: Is this only when running a game? Or does this also occur on times when you are practically doing nothing?

Comment: No it's not. It also occurs when I'm doing nothing as you mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagnose the cause of black screen in Windows 10 OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1655857/how-to-diagnose-the-cause-of-black-screen-in-windows-10-os)

Answer (score -1):

Having the same issue with same board and Cpu that I’m troubleshooting for a customer, but with an rx 580. Im wondering if these boards are susceptible to electrostatic discharge from dust. I tested the gpu in another system, no crash. I booted up from another ssd with no crashes. It looked like it was software so I reinstalled windows 10 and it didn’t crash the whole night while I was stress testing with MSI kombustor (cpu and gpu). So I cleaned off the case and it crashed twice within 10 minutes. At this moment I’m running the stress test again and about 15 minutes in. When I first got it I could barely even get into a game without it bsod. I think there was dust build up causing intermittent crashing.

Comment: as an electrical engineer: "electrostatic discharge from dust": Um, do you happen to operate your GPUs next to a megavolt generator?

Comment: next to a *dusty* megavolt generator?