# How to diagnose the cause of black screen in Windows 10 OS?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, power-supply, hardware-failure

I'm running into some problems with random black screens as described in another question:
[random black screens](https://superuser.com/questions/1610628/black-screen-and-sound-stops-working-but-pc-is-still-running)

As I have not received so far, no reply that could help debug the cause of this black screen.
I would like to ask the following question

**Question**:
Are there any programs that can be run in the background that would collect some logs so that I could debug the cause of the black screen?

**Here is how this event looks like**
[image]

**Log from event viewer**

- System

  - Provider
    [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
    [ Guid]  {331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}
    EventID 41
    Version 8
    Level 1
    Task 63
    Opcode 0
    Keywords 0x8000400000000002
  - TimeCreated
    [ SystemTime]  2021-06-10T09:01:18.2184072Z
    EventRecordID 10941
    Correlation
  - Execution
    [ ProcessID]  4
    [ ThreadID]  8
    Channel System
    Computer DESKTOP-EOTOOLC
  - Security
    [ UserID]  S-1-5-18
- EventData
  BugcheckCode 0
  BugcheckParameter1 0x0
  BugcheckParameter2 0x0
  BugcheckParameter3 0x0
  BugcheckParameter4 0x0
  SleepInProgress 0
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0
  BootAppStatus 0
  Checkpoint 0
  ConnectedStandbyInProgress false
  SystemSleepTransitionsToOn 0
  CsEntryScenarioInstanceId 0
  BugcheckInfoFromEFI false
  CheckpointStatus 0
  CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2 0
  LongPowerButtonPressDetected false

Comment: If you have a second PC I would set-up a server like VNC that allows you to remote login-in when such a black screen appears and check the different hardware components. Also check Windows system event log for entries.

Comment: can't promise anything, but the start of that scrollbox is probably more interesting, and the general info. could you try to copy and paste the text instead of posting a photo?

Comment: just updated and added the logs

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds like a hardware fault. There's a high chance your system crashes so solidly and quickly that anything that logs to something that survives a reboot can't even do that.

Your best guess is Windows' [*event viewer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer). Maybe it's a device that misbehaves, and you might see log entries of other symptoms of the same device misbehaving. Good luck!

With the added info from event viewer, we can now ask Microsoft's support pages.

You're in [scenario 3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-event-id-41-restart#scen3) from this link. As predicted, the software can't know what's wrong – it's a hardware fault; it might be related to power (but honestly, that can have multiple causes).

Microsoft takes best guesses, too, here, so you only get what you power or thermal problems:

> - Disable overclocking. If the computer has overclocking enabled, disable it. Verify that the issue occurs when the system runs at the correct speed.
> - Check the memory. Use a memory checker to determine the memory health and configuration. Verify that all memory chips run at the same speed and that every chip is configured correctly in the system.
> - Check the power supply. Verify that the power supply has enough wattage to appropriately handle the installed devices. If you added memory, installed a newer processor, installed additional drives, or added external devices, such devices can require more energy than the current power supply can provide consistently. If the computer logged Event ID 41 because the power to the computer was interrupted, consider obtaining an uninterruptible power supply (UPS) such as a battery backup power supply.
> - Check for overheating. Examine the internal temperature of the hardware and check for any overheating components.

All in all what that tells us is that Windows has no more clue than "something is wrong with your hardware, check the most common causes for this problem. We can't diagnose this any better".

As said above: Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, so i checked event viewer and i have error number 41. But as i can see the other flags are zeroed. So as I suppose that the PCU is just broken, because i memtested my RAM and it seems to be okay.

Comment: do you mean CPU? That'd be extremely unlikely. Expect more an unstable power supply chain on a GPU, a misbehaving SATA controller, these kinds of things.

Comment: Sorry i meant PSU, power supply unit. Any ideas how can i test if the SATA Controller missbehaves?

Comment: As said: there's no way. Even if you figure out what it is – unless it's a removable device (in your case: probably the only candidate is the GPU), it means replacing the mainboard. There's nothing to be won here by deeper analysis.

Comment: also, "error number 41" doesn't tell us anything. You'll need to tell us which component that comes from, and if possible, all other information that it encompasses.

Comment: My Windows is running on M2 Samsung 960 evo btw.

Comment: Okay i will provide all details from an event viewer in few hours

Comment: just added how the event looks like

Comment: Interesting thing, my girlfriend borrowed headphones from me and plugged them into her laptop. After a few moments, she received a black screen, the same as I have received so far, is there a chance that this black screen was caused by these headphones? the headphones normally have a 3.5mm jack interface, but I connect them to an external sound card from old headphones, so that I can connect them to the usb.

Comment: I think that in my event viewer i also had some errrors related to some audio device driver, may that be the case?

Comment: Headphones can't make a computer crash.

Comment: But it's kinda strange that she also noticed the same black screen on other device :/

Comment: yes, it is. But your headset isn't causing it. Correlation != causation. Headphones are just dumb analog devices. Even a short circuit in the headphone connector doesn't make a laptop do anything but detect a broken headphone.

Comment: Anyway, now with the current info in your question: Updated my answer. Would actually like that upvote by now!

Comment: The update is that I've bought a new monitor and this issue is not happening.